# When did the к/ч consonant alteration appear in Russian? Когда в русском языке впервые появилось чередование к/ч?

Tags: история-языка

In words like век - вечный, урок - урочный, доска - досочка or миска - мисочка. Can this be a result of Uralic influence?

В словах наподобие век - вечный, урок - урочный, доска - досочка или миска - мисочка. Может ли это быть результатом влияния уральских языков?

Answer (score 6):

к/ч consonant alteration is the result of **Slavic first palatalization**. It happened because inherited velars *k and *g had no soft counterparts in Proto-Slavic, so they changed before front vowels *e/ē, *i/ī, and also before the palatal semivowel *j.

Researchers argue about dating of this process. Some believe it happened during VI-V centuries BC, and some postpone it to V—VI CE. I found no direct evidence, and I'm not a specialist in language or Slavic history, but it seems highly unlikely to me that this process had Uralic influence.

You can find more on Wikipedia:

- [Первая палатализация](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)
- [Slavic first palatalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_first_palatalization)

Comment: a very nice answer!

Answer (score -1):

http://www.kls.ksu.ru/krush/articles.php?id=6&num=2000000

Try this. It's a complex research of alteration in Russian.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.